# Doesn't redirect to relative callback url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, next-auth

I don't get the **clearer explanation** based on NextAuth docs. But I have the requirement when user visit the protected page and login, it redirects back again to protected page that user has been visited before.

I set **multilingual** website with NextJS locale. I'm using **googleProvider** as OAuth login.

This is my code:

```
export default NextAuth({
    adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise),
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    providers: [
        // OAuth authentication providers
        GoogleProvider({
            clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
            clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
        }),
    ],
    callbacks: {
        async redirect({ url, baseUrl }) {
            // Allows relative callback URLs
            if (url.startsWith("/en-US")) return `${baseUrl}/en-US/${url}`
            // Allows callback URLs on the same origin
            else if (new URL(url).origin === baseUrl) return url
            return baseUrl
        }

    }
})
```

The google Button (on custom login page):

```
 <Button fullWidth size="large" color="inherit" variant="outlined" onClick={() => signIn("google",
                // { callbackUrl: locale == "id-ID" ? '/app' : "/en-US/app" }
            )}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible workaround is to use getServerSideProps if it is suitable to extend the app to.
If session of next-auth is used, cookies are in the browser, and this can serve:

```
export const getServerSideProps = async (context: any | undefined) => {
  const session = await getSession(context);
  const { locale } = context;
 
  if (session...(SOME CONDITION)) {
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: '/protected',
        permanent: false,
      },
    };
  } 

  return {
    props: {
      sess: session,
     [ possible addition:...await (if there are the things you do server side with locale)]

    },
  };
};
```